# How can we select existing image for image field?

Tags: drupal

I need to select existing image for image field not new upload of image in drupal6X

Answer (score 0):

The [IMCE module](http://drupal.org/project/imce) lets you browse images on the server and select them for inclusion in your compose field.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [ImageField Assist](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_assist) module. Inserting already uploaded images is as easy as clicking an image button. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module can use every single ImageField field added to any node in a Drupal 6 website, and uses ImageCache presets to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Its very late but...here is the answer [IMCE Filefield](http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield)

Cheers!!!